# For command inside a batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I'm wondering why this comand works pasted inside a console:

```
for /d /r "%Programfiles(x86)%\soft_to_remove" %d in (unins000.exe) do @if exist "%d" %d /silent
```

but if I paste it inside bat file, doesn't works with the error:

```
d" d /silent was unexpected at this time.
```

Seems a problem with the variable but I don't figure what to do.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The % has a special function in batch files. To use the character "%", just do it twice. When you put the command into a batch file, use %%d, vice %d.